# How to read json array?

Tags: c#, json

I have json file:

```
[{
    "name": "SiO2",
    "h": 906,
    "s": -477,
    "a": 44,
    "b": 67,
    "c": 47
  },
  {
    "name": "Al2O3",
    "h": 805,
    "s": -155,
    "a": 53,
    "b": 73,
    "c": 62
  }
...
]
```

And I try read all objects via Newtonsoft.Json

```
public class CompoundProps
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public float h { set; get; }
    public float s { set; get; }
    public float a { set; get; }
    public float b { set; get; }
    public float c { set; get; }
}

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Thermo.db1.json");
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
{
    string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
    CompoundProps props = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompoundProps>(data);
    Console.WriteLine(props.name);
}
```

But I have Error:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Thermo.CompoundProps' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Where is incorrect code?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code, look at json and error message? Especially at this part _change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface_ Square brackets in your json tell about it

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski if I remove square brackets I get next error
>"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 8, position 1."

Comment: I don't know how much you know C#, but you are trying to deserialize a single object. You need to tell the deserializer to deserialize into a list of objects of your type like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompoundProps>>(data)`;

Comment: @MatJ yes, I know C# a little bit, I am newbie. Your code call new error "can't transform type" https://prnt.sc/sdsgto

Comment: you need to change that left side of the equal sign also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the deserialization fails is because you are trying to deserialize a collection of `CompoundProps` as `CompoundProps`.
Please try to replace it with: `List<CompoundProps> props = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompoundProps>>();`

Comment: Now I don't have the error. And how can I get value of key from object? For example ```Console.WriteLine(props.name);``` does't work now

Comment: @EugeneChefranov, You need to do a loop like [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

Comment: Props now is a list. Read about collections in c#, basically you can just refer to props[0] and youll have the first CompoundProps in your hand.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are trying to deserialize several `CompoundProps`from your JSON file into one single `CompoundProps` object.
Maybe you should try to deserialize it to a `List<CompoundProps>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the whole solution. You canntry this:
Prinzipiell this way works

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

public class ClassName {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string edition { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
}
```

List list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(json);

This should help.